# Clojure - partitioning by set value

Tags: arrays, sorting, clojure, partitioning

I have a query which returns a count of objects grouped by these objects in a table although what I want to do afterwards is to firstly sort the values from highest to lowest and the partition them into 10 groups.

What I have so far allows me to either sort the counted values from max to min or, if i comment the sort out, or partition the values by a set number. I would like to know where Im going wrong here because I cant see it. I am pulling the count of objects from the query initially, sorting and then trying to partition them into arrays which I will index at a later stage:

```
tosort(map(keyword :objectscounted)data)
sorted(sort > tosort)
part(into [] (partition-all 10 sorted))
```

Where I am also stuck is when using the partition - I need 10 groups of values, not 10 values in each group, any help here is appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your problem, all you need is to partition dynamically according to your `sorted` list element count:

```
user> (def v (range 50))
#'user/v
user> (clojure.pprint/pprint (partition-all (/ (count v) 10) v))
((0 1 2 3 4)
 (5 6 7 8 9)
 (10 11 12 13 14)
 (15 16 17 18 19)
 (20 21 22 23 24)
 (25 26 27 28 29)
 (30 31 32 33 34)
 (35 36 37 38 39)
 (40 41 42 43 44)
 (45 46 47 48 49))
```

Of course if total elements is not divisible by 10, your result will have have more than 10 groups, unless you have a different strategy to distribute elements among groups.